# Stuck at Human Verification

Tags: support, bug

I am trying to post an answer on TeX.SE and am stuck at:

[image]

The dots continue and I never see the captcha.  For some reason, `meta.TeX.SE` does not have a concern with me being human.

Also, why is there not an exception for this once you reach a certain rep cap? It seems that this is needed only for really really new users.  Have encountered this a few times in the past and find it quite annoying.

I like procrastinating as much as the loyal TeX.SE users, but this is getting in the way!! :-)

Comment: Do you have ad blocker of some sort interfering with captcha? To be honest, I think captchas are just lame.

Comment: @percusse: I have not made any setting changes in quite some time. The only thing different this time was that I was on one wi-fi in middle of composing an answer and got kicked off so move to a different location - once at the new location I am stuck and can no longer post an answer on TeX.SE.

Comment: @percusse: Finally am human again. Feel much better. Now back to finding some more green ticks for the day :-)

Comment: I've seen this happen when I compose a solution on one network connect, then close down and relocate, and when I join another network and then make the post. Perhaps the human verification includes a check whether we are stationary as bots may have a tendency to post from different locations to avoid (or make difficult any form of) tracking.

Comment: @PeterGrill Haha, godspeed iRobot.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I'm interested to know; were you in/out of multiple network connections or stationary?

Comment: @Werner: I switched to a totally different network connection in the middle of composing a solution, so seems to be same problem you experienced.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the captcha has detected alien activity and you are not in fact a human being?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: :-) Perhaps I should have been more careful when I reproduced precisely what trees look like where I am from: [referring to tikz picture again in the same latex document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101201/4301).

Comment: Same for me here: http://i.imgur.com/52YM4iw.png -- seriously, investing half an hour to write an answer only to be harassed by the captcha bouncer does not make for a pleasant experience. Is this some kind of reverse Turing test that I have to vindicate  my humanity to?

Comment: @phg: Sorry to hear that you are having such a bad experience. I think for me when I have had these problems it had to do switching between networks during the session. I just think that SE should disable these once you have enough rep.